# Integrating Flash animations into Android games

Tags: android, flash, animation

I'm developing a game and want to integrate some animations, I've thought about making them in Flash and integrating in Android, is it possible in general? If yes, does it make sense? How will it look in terms of user experience, performance and app size? What are other ways to create game animations in Android? Thanks in advance for your answers, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: yes, it is possible.
But in general you would like to avoid it, unless it's some very simple animations. You may want to bake animations in bitmaps and use them in that way. Memory consuming, but CPU will thank you :) Also, for spatial animations, you can use tools like [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/).
If you want special effects stuff, use particle engine like [Flint](http://flintparticles.org/).
All of this is true if you using air as a platform :)